# PHP Syntax with Query and PDO use

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to make a php login file that queries my SQL database for the correct username and password. My `checklogin.php` seems to hang when I call my method from `dao.php`. I have a `register.php` that works fine with my `dao.php`. Below is all my code. I believe my problem is coming from the getUser() function in `dao.php`.

```
checklogin.php:

    <?php
  require_once "DAO.php";
  $dao = new DAO();

  // Get data from form POST
  $username = (isset($_POST["username"])) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
  $password = (isset($_POST["password"])) ? $_POST["password"] : "";

  // MySQL Injection Protection Section (the rhymez)
  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $password = stripslashes($password);

  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  // End protection

  //echo $username;
  //echo $password;
  //echo $dao->getUser($username, $password);

  if(!$dao->getUser($username, $password)){
    //echo "Wrong usernamer or password";
    header("location: login.html");
  }
  else{
    //echo "Logic successful";
    header("location: index.php");
  }
?>
```

dao.php:

```
    <?php
    class DAO {
      private $host = "localhost";
      private $db = "webdev";
      private $user = "root";
      private $pass = "secret";

      public function getConnection () {
        //echo "hello";
        try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->db}", $this->user,$this->pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        //echo "success";
        return $dbh;
      }

      public function registerUser($username, $password, $email, $name) {
        $conn = $this->getConnection();
        $saveQuery = "INSERT INTO users(login, pass, email, fname) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :name)";
        $q = $conn->prepare($saveQuery);
        $q->bindParam(":username", $username);
        $q->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $q->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $q->bindParam(":name", $name);
        $q->execute();
      }

      public function getUser($username, $password){
        $conn = $this->getConnection();
        $getQuery = "SELECT login FROM users where login=:username and pass=:password";
        $q = $conn->prepare($getQuery);
        $q->bindParam(":username" $username);
        $q->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $q->execute();

        //$conn->query($getQuery);
        $count = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if($count == 1){
          echo "hi";
          session_register(":username");
          return true;
        }
        else{
          echo "hi";
          return false;
        }
      }
    } // end Dao
    ?>
```

register.php:

```
<?php
  require_once "DAO.php";
  $dao = new DAO();

  // Get data from form POST
  $username = (isset($_POST["username"])) ? $_POST["username"] : die('Error: Username / Password field was blank');
  $password = (isset($_POST["password"])) ? $_POST["password"] : header("location: index.php");
  $email = (isset($_POST["email"])) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
  $name = (isset($_POST["name"])) ? $_POST["name"] : "";

  // MySQL Injection Protection Section (the rhymez)
  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $password = stripslashes($password);
  $email = stripslashes($email);
  $name = stripslashes($name);

  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
  // End protection

  $dao->registerUser($username, $password, $email, $name);
  header("location: appointment.php");
?>
```

**EDIT (solved it):**
Figured it out. I used bits from Your Common Sense's code to solve it.

```
getUser function:

      public function getUser($username, $password){
        $conn = $this->getConnection();
        $getQuery = "SELECT login FROM users WHERE login=:username AND pass=:password";
        $q = $conn->prepare($getQuery);
        $q->bindParam(":username", $username);
        $q->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $q->execute();

        $rows = $q->fetchAll();
        return empty($rows); // True if account doesn't exist
      }
```

checklogin.php:

```
<?php
      require_once "DAO.php";
      $dao = new DAO();

      // Get data from form POST
      $username = (isset($_POST["username"])) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
      $password = (isset($_POST["password"])) ? $_POST["password"] : "";

      // MySQL Injection Protection Section (the rhymez)
      $username = stripslashes($username);
      $password = stripslashes($password);
      // End protection

      // Failure
      if($dao->getUser($username, $password)){
        header("location: login.html");
      }
      // Successful login
      else{
        header("location: index.php");
      }
    ?>
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Don't use mysql_real_escape_string with PDO. If you use proper parameters you don't need to and it might actually be the cause of your problem, although actual 'hanging' is odd.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about dumping all the code without debugging it to only the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1):

There are SO MUCH wrong with this code that it will take a week to explain all the errors, wrong practices and superstitions. So, code only

```
class DAO {

  function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->db = $pdo;
  }

  public function registerUser($username, $password, $email, $name) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(login, pass, email, fname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(func_get_args());
  }

  public function getUser($username, $password){
    $sql = "SELECT id,password FROM users where login=?";
    $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute([$username]);
    $row = $stm->fetch();
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['id'];
        return TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

checklogin.php:

```
<?php
require_once "DAO.php";
require_once "pdo.php";
$dao = new DAO($pdo);

if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $dao->getUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]))
{
    header("location: index.php");

} else {

    header("location: login.html");
}
```

register.php:

```
<?php
require_once "DAO.php";
require_once "pdo.php";
$dao = new DAO();

// this section is flawed too but I can't write ALL the app
$username = (isset($_POST["username"])) ? $_POST["username"] : die('Error: Username / Password field was blank');
$password = (isset($_POST["password"])) ? $_POST["password"] : header("location: index.php");
$email = (isset($_POST["email"])) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
$name = (isset($_POST["name"])) ? $_POST["name"] : "";

$dao->registerUser($username, $password, $email, $name);
header("location: appointment.php");
```

pdo.php

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webdev;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','secret', $opt);
```

Comment: Copied everything you have, now my register and login load a blank page where the URL is register.php and checklogin.php, respectively. My register worked fine before but the checklogin would be a blank page.